# How to insert a record having foregin key using slick 3?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0, play-slick

I have two models:

```
case class User(uid: Option[Int], email: String, password: String, created_at: Timestamp, updated_at: Timestamp)

case class UserProfile(firstname: String, lastname: String, gender: Int, user_id: Long),
```

And a DAO with user table defined:

```
package dao

import java.sql.Timestamp

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import javax.inject.Inject

import models.{User, UserProfile}
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.db.slick.HasDatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.profile.SqlProfile.ColumnOption.SqlType
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import com.github.t3hnar.bcrypt._

class UsersDAO @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  private val Users = TableQuery[UsersTable]
  private val UsersProfile = TableQuery[UserProfileTable]


  def all(): Future[Seq[User]] = db.run(Users.result)

  def insert(user: User): Future[Int] = {
    println("coming inside insert of user dao")
    println(user)
//    insertUP(user)
    val hashPassword = user.password.bcrypt
    val updatedUser = user.copy(password = hashPassword)

    val query = db.run((Users returning Users.map(_.uid)) += updatedUser)
//    val uid = Await.result(query, 30 seconds)
//    println(s"UID ---------> $uid")
    query
  }




  def findByEmail(email: String): Option[User] = {

    val query = for {
      u <- Users if u.email === email
    } yield u

    val f: Future[Option[User]] = db.run(query.result).map(_.headOption)
    val result = Await.result(f, 30 seconds)
    println(result.isDefined)
    result
  }

  def authenticate(username: String, password: String): Future[Option[User]] = {

    val query = db.run(Users.filter(_.email === username).result.map(_.headOption.filter(user => password.isBcrypted(user.password)))).map(_.headOption)

    query
  }

  private class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

    def uid = column[Int]("uid", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.SqlType("INT"))
    def email = column[String]("email")
    def password = column[String]("password")
    def created_at = column[Timestamp]("created_at", SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    def updated_at = column[Timestamp]("updated_at", SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    def idx = index("email_UNIQUE", email, unique = true)

    def * = (uid.?, email, password, created_at, updated_at) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
  }

  private class UserProfileTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserProfile](tag, "user_profile"){

    def firstname = column[String]("firstname")
    def lastname = column[String]("lastname")
    def gender = column[Int]("gender")
    def user_id = column[Int]("user_id")

    def * = (firstname, lastname, gender, user_id) <> (UserProfile.tupled, UserProfile.unapply)

    def fk_user_id = foreignKey("fk_user_id", user_id, Users)(_.uid)
  }



}
```

In the insert function, how could I add uid to user_id field of user profile table in the same function or call?

---

### Edit 1

Tried the solution suggested by Pawel, but getting exception:

```
failed slick.SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT
```

---

### Edit - 2

Now, after trying some solutions, the insert function is like this:

```
def insert(user: User): Future[Int] = {
    val hashPassword = user.password.bcrypt
    val updatedUser  = user.copy(password = hashPassword)

    val insertUser = (Users returning Users.map(_.uid)) += updatedUser
    def insertUserProfile(updatedUserProfile: UserProfile) = (UsersProfile returning UsersProfile.map(_.user_id)) += updatedUserProfile

    val insertUserThenProfile = for {
      createdUserId        <- insertUser
      createdUserProfileId <- insertUserProfile(UserProfile("First name", "Last name", gender = 0, user_id = createdUserId))
    } yield createdUserProfileId

    db.run(insertUserThenProfile.transactionally)
  }
```

But still getting the error:
`failed slick.SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT`

---

### Solution

Pawels solution should work fine, but some DBMS gives exception for not returning AUtoInc field, and for trying to return something else. 
You can see the note in documentation:
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html

```
Note

Many database systems only allow a single column to be returned which must be the table’s auto-incrementing primary key. If you ask for other columns a SlickException is thrown at runtime (unless the database actually supports it).
```

So, Now, my models are like this:

```
case class User(uid: Option[Int], email: String, password: String, created_at: Timestamp, updated_at: Timestamp)

case class UserProfile(upid: Option[Int], firstname: String, lastname: String, gender: Int, user_id: Int)
```

And the Table class:

```
private class UserProfileTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserProfile](tag, "user_profile"){

    def upid= column[Int]("upid", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc, O.SqlType("INT"), O.Default(0))
    def firstname = column[String]("firstname")
    def lastname = column[String]("lastname")
    def gender = column[Int]("gender")
    def user_id = column[Int]("user_id")

    def * = (upid.?, firstname, lastname, gender, user_id) <> (UserProfile.tupled, UserProfile.unapply)

    def fk_user_id = foreignKey("fk_user_id", user_id, Users)(_.uid)
  }
```

And finally the insert method:

```
def insert(user: User): Future[Int] = {
    val hashPassword = user.password.bcrypt
    val updatedUser  = user.copy(password = hashPassword)

    val insertUser = (Users returning Users.map(_.uid)) += updatedUser
    def insertUserProfile(updatedUserProfile: UserProfile) = (UsersProfile returning UsersProfile.map(_.upid)) += updatedUserProfile

    val insertUserThenProfile = for {
      createdUserId        <- insertUser
      createdUserProfileId <- insertUserProfile(UserProfile(Some(0), "First name", "Last name", gender = 0, user_id = createdUserId))
    } yield createdUserProfileId

    db.run(insertUserThenProfile.transactionally)
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to add both `User` and `UserProfile` in that `insert` method?

Comment: @PawełJurczenko yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how are you planning to provide values for `UserProfile` (it's up to you, maybe an additional parameter in the `insert` method), but I would try something like this:

```
def insert(user: User): Future[UserProfile] = {
  val hashPassword = user.password.bcrypt
  val updatedUser  = user.copy(password = hashPassword)

  val insertUser = (Users returning Users.map(_.uid)) += updatedUser
  def insertUserProfile(updatedUserProfile: UserProfile) = (UsersProfile returning UsersProfile.map(_.user_id)) += updatedUserProfile

  val insertUserThenProfile = for {
    createdUserId        <- insertUser
    createdUserProfileId <- insertUserProfile(UserProfile("First name", "Last name", gender = 0, user_id = createdUserId))
  } yield createdUserProfileId

  db.run(insertUserThenProfile.transactionally)
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but I am getting: `failed slick.SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT`

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It is Mysql 5 version

Comment: I have updated my answer, this should be working now.

Comment: Nope, still its complaining about the same.

Comment: Could you check the solution now? I have updated another thing.

Comment: Now, I get this compilation error: `type mismatch;
 found   : slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write with slick.dbio.Effect.Write with slick.dbio.Effect.Transactional]
 required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[models.UserProfile,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]
`

Comment: I have updated my question in Edit - 2. I had to change the return signature to Future[Int], but still its the same error.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're importing `slick.driver.JdbcProfile` instead of `slick.driver.MySQLDriver`?

Comment: I solved it :), will update my question and tag your solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a query to insert a new Member and return the member with its id

```
val memberWithId = (queryMember returning queryMember.map(_.id) into ((c, id) => c.copy(id = id))) += registerMember.copy(password = pwHash)
```

Then implement the query as a transaction. Insert Member, insert User Profile(you can use the id from the success of the first statement)

```
val transaction = (for {
  m: Member <- memberWithId
  p: UsersProfile <- queryProfile returning queryProfile += MemberProfile(m.id, firstName, ...)
} yield m).transactionally
```

Run it as a Try so that you can more easily parse errors rather than crashing.

```
db.run(transaction.asTry)
```